# Summernote v0.7.0 on change callback issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Having a simple set up for summernote.

```
<div id="summernote">data-here</div>


$('#summernote').summernote({
  height: 200,                 // set editor height
  focus: true,
  callbacks // any callbacks didn't worked, onChange, onBlur etc..(any tip on how to add proper callbacks here)
});
```

I tried to make jquery code to catch on change event of my summernote, like:

```
$('#summernote').on("summernote.change", function (e) {
 # Problem here when deleting (keyboard backspace, calls twice)
 -some code here-
}
```

My problem with the `summernote.change` is that when deleting text/content using keybord's backspace, the callback (on change) triggers twice instead.
Thus my inside function runs twice too.

Any idea on this guys, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it’s a known issue (https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2888), but nobody tried to fix it.

So, I use it like this :

```js
        var mySec = 100;
        var myEvent;

        $('#summernote').on("summernote.change", function (e) {
            clearTimeout(myEvent);

            myEvent = setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(e) // do something!
            }, mySec);
        });
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Works well, summernote.focus for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate the issue. But it works fine for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 200, // set editor height
    focus: true,
    callbacks: {
      onInit: function() {
        console.log('Summernote is launched');
      },
      onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
        console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
      }
    }
  });
  $('#summernote').on('summernote.change', function(we, contents, $editable) {
    console.log('summernote.change', contents, $editable);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.js"></script>

<div id="summernote">data-here</div>
```

**Note:** You should use either of the events `onChange` in callbacks or `summernote.change` not both.

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thank you for the answer. You're not reproducing the issue because the version is different. Still a help for me oneday when to upgrade to that version. :)